# How to split FHS read-only and read/write directories across two disks with Linux/systemd, without partitioning the raed/write disk?

Tags: partition, systemd, symlink, fhs, bind-mount

My objective is to have the physical storage for the Linux FHS read/write directories (`/home`, `/srv`, `/tmp`, `/var`) on a separate (logical or physical) disk from the potentially read-only rest of the root file system.

I know I can create four partitions on my second disk and use each partition for one of the beforementioned directories using `mount`. But I don't feel like determining the required storage space for the four directories upfront, even if I may be able to correct the sizes of the (logical or physical) partitions later.

Can this be achieved and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a distro with a merged `/usr`; then you can mount `/usr` RO and the rest RW, and have most of the relevant stuff RO. This doesn't catch `/etc`, though, which you might want. Not quite a solution, more a workaround.

Another is to make a single BTRFS volume with subvolumes for all the mounts you want, then mount with `-osubvol=<whatever>`. These mounts can have individual mount options, but in the default configuration (without any quota setup) they'll all count against the entire BTRFS volume space-wise, such that you'll be able to put new data anywhere you like as long as the whole FS has space left.

Comment: I'm choosing this answer because the BTRFS subvolume approach is probably the way to go in the future. Whoever comes across this and still lives in a [pre-BTRFS era will probably want to look at the answer describing symbolic links and bind mounts](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241844/79761).

Answer (score 3):

Similar questions have been asked before. The closest appears to be [How to mount multiple directories on the same partition?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/47222/79761) where [this currently accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47224/79761) suggests that it can be in two ways:

- Using four _symbolic links: in the root filesystem, pointing to four individual subtrees on the second disk, which itself is mounted once to a mount point independent of the four directories.
- Using *bind mounts* (available since Linux 2.4) to mount four individual subtrees on the second disk to the four directories, after the second disk is first mounted to a mount point independent of the four directories.

The same answer has an interesting comment which points to [this Q&A discussing pros and cons of *symbolic links* vs *bind mounts*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/49623/79761). From this, one would conclude that *symbolic links* should be preferred, because they're easier to see and maintain and will cause no trouble with any existing software.

However, `systemd` has an explicit dependency configuration feature called `RequiresMountsFor`. E.g. the standard Debian 8 (Jessie) uses it to make some services wait for potential mounts of `/var`, which needs to be available for the services in question.

**`systemd`'s `RequiresMountsFor` will only work with *bind mounts***; not with *symbolic links*.

At least the Debian 8 `systemd` service configuration files in question are located in `/lib/systemd` so they are not meant to be modified. This suggests that ***bind mounts* should be preferred if you use a Linux distribution which introduces such `systemd` dependencies**. Modifying the `systemd` configuration of the Linux distribution may turn system maintenance into a nightmare.

The presence of `systemd` itself, on the other hand, does not constitute a pro or con point for the choice between *symbolic links* and *bind mounts*.

Comment: Assume symbolic links are instantaneous. In that case, simply require mount of the single mountpoint of the 2nd disk. In other words - systemd shouldn't affect your choice of bind mount vs. symbolic links.

Comment: @Dani_l I see your point but I'm in a pragmatic mood today. Debian's choice of making services wait for `/var` to be available is made in `systemd` config files located in `/lib/systemd`, not in `/etc/systemd`. I guess changing these Debian distro files will turn system updates into a nightmare. So although I had a slight preference in favour of _symbolic links_, this changed since I don't want to be at the maintainer's mercy.

Comment: Fine, in that case modify your answer to reflect that /var mount requirement is pushed by distro, so it's easier to maintain or something to that effect.

Comment: @Dani_l Good point. I've tried to make that more clear now. Thank you for your valuable feedback.

Comment: symlinks are messy. `/etc/fstab` is nice. another way to do it without specifying explicit size is with btrfs subvolumes.

Comment: also the linked discussion on `--bind` mounts is incorrect. `mount --bind dir1 dir2` is only *one* way to `mount --bind`. a linux kernel maintains an entire mount propagation tree, and mounts can be specified per process, per path, per user, or many combinations thereof. its why `systemd` wants `--bind` mounts in the first place *(besides the mount being more secure, that is)*.

Comment: I feel like having opened a box full of surprises. @mikeserv Are you suggesting that the presence of `systemd` is, in itself, a point on favour of _bind mounts_?

Comment: no. systemd is a soul-devouring octopus. but bind mounts are secure and handled in kernel, and so systemd chooses correctly in this case.